# How can I add to a List's first position?

Tags: c#, list

I just have a `List<T>` and I would like to add an item to this list but at the first position.
`MyList.add()` adds the item as the last. How can I add it as the first?.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 444, accepted):

```
List<T>.Insert(0, item);
```

Answer (score 95):

```
 myList.Insert(0, item);
```

---

This does involve shifting all the contents of the List internally so if you do this a lot (ie only add to the front) you might consider using a `Stack<T>` or a regular List that you read backwards or reverse at some opportune moment.

I would stay away from LinkedList (as long as i could).

Answer (score 30):

Use `List.Insert(0, ...)`. But are you sure a [`LinkedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) isn't a better fit? Each time you insert an item into an array at a position other than the array end, all existing items will have to be copied to make space for the new one.

Answer (score 19):

Use `List<T>.Insert(0, item)` or a `LinkedList<T>.AddFirst()`.

Answer (score 12):

You do that by inserting into position 0:

```
List myList = new List();
myList.Insert(0, "test");
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `Insert` method:
    list.Insert(0, item);

Answer (score 9):

Of course, `Insert` or `AddFirst` (for a LinkedList) will do the trick, but you could always do:

```
myList.Reverse();
myList.Add(item);
myList.Reverse();
```

> **Note** that while this will get you there eventually, it sure is not the most effective way to go ;).

Comment: Let me clarify - this is not a serious response, just a lame effort at a geek joke.